# Torch DoubleTensor CharTensor Incompatibility

Tags: lua, neural-network, torch

Essentially how does one multiply a CharTensor mask with a DoubleTensor? I making a module for torch, it is supposed to be similar to the ReLU module. Therefore self.mask is supposed to be a mask of 0s and 1s that I want to hit the DoubleTensor self.output with. Currently self.mask is a CharTensor and I am not able to multiply the two as seen in the log. It seems so trivial but I have been looking online forever now, unable to find a solution.

Infinite thanks,

-an anxious coder

function ReQU:updateOutput(input)

...

self.mask = torch.gt(input, 0)

self.output:cmul(self.mask)

...

Log:
invalid arguments: DoubleTensor ByteTensor 
expected arguments: *DoubleTensor* [DoubleTensor] DoubleTensor
stack traceback:
    [C]: in function 'cmul'
    ./requ.lua:21: in function 'forward'

Answer (score 2):

Torch exposes methods to do this without the need to multiply values by yourself. The simplest is probably to invert your mask and use the [index `[]` operator](https://github.com/torch/torch7/blob/master/doc/tensor.md#tensor--dim1dim2--or--dim1sdim1e-dim2sdim2e-):

```
self.mask = torch.le(input, 0)
self.output[self.mask] = 0
```

Comment: Thank you for the pithy reply!